# pip install tensorflow: pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out

Tags: python, pip

I get this error when I try to install tensorflow

```
pip install tensorflow


pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.


pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto', None, 10054, None))
```

I tried with

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Also

```
pip3 install tensorflow

pip3 install tensorflow --time-out=1000

pip install tensorflow --timeout-out=1000 future
```

But still got this error.

Comment: just download wheel file from pypi and then install from that file

Comment: did you find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download 'Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable', because it's a requirement. This is the link in which you can download it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

I hope this solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).